# Laravel webpack.mix: line break in font import string appears when scss translated to css

Tags: laravel, webpack, import, fonts, laravel-mix

I use *laravel* with *webpack.mix* and I import public google font to *app.scss* file:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');
```

(no one spaces or line breaks in this first string!)

*Webpack.mix* command looks common:

```
 mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

and translate this ***s**css* file to *css*.
BUT in css I get:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;

400;500&display=swap);
```

What the hell this weird line break appears from?! Browser cant see the font this way  =
I tried npm run dev, run prod. Check original string 20 times...

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to use `%3b` instead of `;` in your link.

Reference: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2430#issuecomment-653915587